# Windows server and ddns which binding and sql hostname do i use?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

i'm trying to connect to websites on this server from outside the network. i've opened ports in router and firewall and can ping the ports using portchecker. let's pretend i want to use wordpress or dotnetnuke(but not the web platform versions as i have sql 2014) . I signed up for a free ddns at no-ip.com

example.ddns.net

**installation screen for any normal cms/blog wants your sql/mysql hostname & iis binding needs hostname as well**

- on normal first-time installation page...localhost? example.ddns.net? the static ip i setup for this server?
- in the iis settings what do i use for the binding? i added one for
  each of what i thought most likely. 192.168.1.141, example.ddns.net,
  and localhost. *(see below for which worked)*

**note:** *if i go into iis, right click the project i want to expose to internet, and set the 'physical path credentials' to an admin account and pw...it lets me see all 3 of them, and lets me use example.ddns.net from outside the network. so this may be a file permission problem?*

**second note:** *if i try and use IUSR or IIS_IUSRS as the anonymous credential(instead of app pool identity) or as physical path credential it says i need a password??*

**Third note:** *i had never heard of RFC1918, so i don't know if the static ip i setup for ipv4 is a valid ip to use for this server. 192.168.1.141 (and reserved that on routers dhcp)*

**fourth note** *let windows server do a standard install and then added a bunch of roles and then removed them. added a whole lot of certification/AD roles because i thought it'd be nice to let all my old home pc's connect and do backups and such. I then  removed AD (cert, domain, directory rights), application serv, dhcp server, dns server, deployment services, and maybe a few others i had originally added*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a CMS using its Install page, it wants this information to know where your website lives, and what to call it - So all links it creates on your Backend are pointing in the right place.

So if your website is **example.ddns.net** then that will be your **hostname on your CMS as well as in IIS.**

Your **IP address in IIS will be your local IP address** which you have assigned to that server or public if you are connecting a server directly to the internet using DMZ or other setup where your Public IP is directly assigned to that server.

As long as your CMS is on the IIS server and your DB is on the same server then **localhost will be just fine, however you will need to change this if you are remotely connecting to the DB** over the internet or LAN - In which case you will need to allow remote connections for that other specific IP address so your CMS can talk to your DB.

I hope I have made my answer clear enough for you and that it answers your questions, I can elaborate on/edit my answer if necessary.

Comment: thanks @NickDodd for the reply! i thought for about 30 minutes before i posted to make sure i wouldn't get down-voted! i have a quick follow up question to make sure i use your instructions correctly... in the site bindings panel on IIS*8/8.5 i believe* i use type: http and then Host Name: example.ddns.net and THEN put the ip address in the IP address box as well? or do i do those seperately?

Comment: Sorry about the massive amount of time since posting my answer, and I hope you have since resolved the problem, if you have not:

on IIS Bindings, you will see "IP Address" where you put your local (or All unassigned if you have dynamic) - and under "Host name" you will put which domain the website will answer page requests for.